# How to append ruby tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, append

I want to do the following in a js function:

```
var ul = $('#teams_div');
var html = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="teams_ul"><% Team.where(["champeonship_id >='+ id+'"]).each do |team| %><li><a><%= team.name %></a></li><%end%></ul>';
ul.append(html);
```

The problem is that when the var html is injected

```
<% Team.where(["champeonship_id >='+ id+'"]).each do |team| %>
```

and

```
<%end%>
```

is inserted as string ("<% Team.where(["champeonship_id >='+ id+'"]).each do |team| %>") so is not evaluated.
But

```
<li><a><%= team.name %></a></li>
```

is injected correctly

what could be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<%= team.name %> works beacuse it is echoed using <%= %>, whereas <% Team ... it is not. (Note the "<%" as opposed to "<%=" )

Try:

```
var ul = $('#teams_div');
var html = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="teams_ul">';
<% Team.where(["champeonship_id >='+ id+'"]).each do |team| %>
   html += '<li><a><%= team.name %></a</li>';
<%end%>
html += '</ul>';
ul.append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, several issues here

--

**Javascript**

Firstly, you're calling Ruby code in javascript.

If this is in the [`asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) (IE `/app/assets/javascripts/...`), it simply won't work. Ruby ERB code, to the best of my knowledge, doesn't work in the asset pipeline.

As such, you need to extract the ruby code from your JS, and either use an Ajax call, or hidden div, to show it in your application:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$.get( "team_champions/" + id );
```

This will mean you'll be able to call the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :teams do
   collection do
      get "team_champions/:id", to: "team_champions"
   end
end

#app/controllers/teams_controller.rb
Class TeamsController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, only: :team_champions
   def team_champions
       @teams = Team.where("champeonship_id >= #{params[:id]}")
       #rails will render app/views/teams/team_champions.js.erb
   end
end

#app/views/teams/team_champions.js.erb
var ul = $('#teams_div');
var html = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="teams_ul">';

<% @teams.each do |team| %>
   html += '<li><a><%=j team.name %></a></li>';
<% end %>;

html += '</ul>';
ul.append(html);
```

I used `ionut.ciuperca's` loop

This will fire in the background, and should just work for you.

--

**MVC**

Finally, you'll want to read up on the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) -

[image]

Calling a `Model` directly in your view is a big "no-no". You need to make sure you call model data from controllers *only*, allowing to keep your application as *modular* as possible.

My code above demonstrates this principle precisely.

Comment: I have problems including team_champions.js.erb
ERROR:
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
  (in /Users/danielaahumada/Documents/wp-sheets/wp/app/assets/javascripts/teams.js.erb)

The error select this code line
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

Comment: Are you including that JS file directly in your application.js file by any changce?

Comment: I solved it...
Now I don't know why says:
Missing template teams/team_champions, application/team_champions with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/danielaahumada/Documents/wp-sheets/wp/app/views"